# classic asp cint

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new to classic asp, all my experience is in c# .net and ColdFusion and php.

Anyway, this site I'm working on has this code all over the place

```
If (CInt("0" & myVar) > 0) Then
    myNewCar = CInt("0" & myVar)
End If
```

What I don't understand is why the "0" is append to the var in the cint() input? Am I just missing something? Is it some kind of safety thing? Is it efficient?

On a side note, any classic asp books recommended?

Comment: here is a bit of fun.  Add sub can't(

Comment: Add sub cint(Val) cint = clng(Val) end sub.  Sorry about earlier post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its an old hack to handle null values.  Calling CInt on a null would result in an error.  However concatenating a string with a null results in the string hence "0" & null returns "0".  This prevents CInt from erroring when the value is null.

Answer (score 2):

myVar might be nothing, an object, empty string, or non-numeric.  Pre-pending "0" guarantees you'll get *some* valid integer back out no matter what.

Comment: CInt(Empty) returns 0.  An attempt to concat "0" with an object that does not have a default property would result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

My classic ASP is a bit rusty, but I believe it's a safety thing.  For instance, if myVar had not been defined and it tried to do a CInt, that would cause an error.

Comment: With option explicit the code would not compile, without Option Explict an undefined variable is dynamically defined and given a value of empty.  Empty values will CInt to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you CInt a null value you will get an error. This is not the case for Cstr

Assuming that checking myVar > 0 is basically a null check.

```
myVar=cstr(myVar)
If (not length(myVar) = 0) Then
    myNewCar = cint(myVar)
End If
```

So myNewCar would either be "" or the value and you'll never get an error